# How to make text appear in an android notification?

Tags: android, notifications

I am trying to create a notification on android in order to notify the user if something is happening. Here is my example code (called from the `MainActivity`)

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.stoxx_icon)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Hello World!");
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
int mId = 1001;
mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
```

The notification is shown on the screen (no lock screen, the normal un-locked screen) and when I swipe the notification bar down (like Figure 2 [in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)) I can see it as well, but the text is like follows:

```
MyApplication
Contents hidden
```

I was expecting to see the following content:

```
My notification
Hello World!
```

I looked in the documentation but did not find anything that I can use to solve my problem(I looked at `setVisibility`, but this seems to be relevant for a lock-screen only which I do not have here). Maybe I overlooked it, but maybe this does nothing have to do with a `Notification`. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Setting `setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)` makes the text readable even on the lock screen (not what I want) and `setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_SECRET)` does not show the notification on the lock screen at all.

What I want:

- lock-screen: notification is shown with 'Contents hidden'
- unlocked screen: notification is shown with content as given in the code.

What I get with `VISIBILITY_PRIVATE`:

- lock-screen: notification is shown with 'Contents hidden'
- unlocked screen: notification is shown with 'Contents hidden'

What I get with `VISIBILITY_PUBLIC`:

- lock-screen: notification is shown with with content as given in the code.
- unlocked screen: notification is shown with with content as given in the code.

What I get with `VISIBILITY_SECRET`:

- lock-screen: notification is not shown at all.
- unlocked screen: unknown

Comment: What you have looks fine. You might try [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Notifications/DownloadNotify) on your environment. If it gives you similar results, then the issue would appear to be tied to the device or emulator that you are using, as I know that sample app works.

Comment: @Alex you have the whole project in that Github, just compile it with Android Studio and run into your device or emulator.

Comment: You can download the whole repo as a ZIP archive: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/archive/master.zip Then, import this one project into your IDE.

Comment: Cannot try it. It requires gradle 1.2, and I have gradle 1.0 installed. I really do not want my other project suddenly failing for some stupid updates...